# Get the text from a radiobuttonlist instead of the value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've searched all over the internet and i can't seem to find a solution to my little problem.
i got this radiobuttonlist where i get the selected value by saying:

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue
```

This works great when trying to get the value

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" CellSpacing="50">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Helt enig"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Delvist enig"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Hverken eller"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Delvist uenig"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Helt uenig"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

But now i've come to the point where i would like to get the text also. 
Usually i would just get it by saying:

```
   RadioButtonList1.Text;
```

But for some reason i just get the "Value" again. 
Does anyone know if there's a way to get the "Text" also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text
```

This should do it.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much! 
I'll accept the answer as soon as it let's me

Comment: No problem at all!, glad i could help